# Is there a way to see all the current Apache rules in effect?

Tags: apache-2.2, command-line-interface, mod-rewrite, rules

Is there a way to see all the current Apache rules in effect?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of flags for:

```
apachectl
```

Otherwise you need to cat the httpd.conf in apache's directory (and all the other files it includes).

To find it:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

And look in the directory in which httpd lives and start from there.

However, this doesn't tell you which rules are in effect for a specific given directory or URL. That gets pretty complicated, given rewrite rules and such. I have never seen a "dump all the rules that affect me if I'm in spot X" tool, though that would be pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

If reading the configuration files is too problematic, you might be able to get their contents in a slightly more script-friendly form from [`mod_info`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_info.html). That reads the configuration files and outputs the parsed results to a web-page at a designated location. You could then run something like `lynx --dump` and might keep it in a fairly regular format.